# Autenticación con netflix-zuul y microservicio con certificados

Tags: java, spring-boot

En mi aplicacion estamos usando la librería de netflix-zuul para llamar a los microservicios de otras aplicaciones, el caso es que tenemos que usar un certificado para poder llamar a estos microservicios y desconozco como hacerlo.

Ahora mismo tengo confirmado en el .yml la llamada a los microservicios:

```
    #configuracion netflix-zuul  
zuul:
  debug:
    request: true
  add-proxy-headers: false
  routes:
    nombreServicio:
      path: /pathServicio/**
      url: URL del servicio al que llamará el path
```

Bien, el caso es que me han dado dos ficheros un .key y un .cer.. pero desconozco como meter estos certificados en mi aplicación.

Entiendo que al añadir los certificados ami app, cuando invoque a los path de netflix-zuul ya cogerían dichos certificados ?

¿Alguna ayuda?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaría agregarlos al cacert de java, de esta manera todo lo que corra en la máquina virtual de java aceptará estos certificados.

en el JAVA_HOME/bin por consola:

keytool -importcert -file mycertfile.cer -keystore cacerts -alias "Alias"

Comment: Tu respuesta no aporta una solución clara al problema, te recomiendo leer [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que te informes de la manera adecuada de responder una pregunta.

Comment: @gcoronel99 por qué no?